# Dual booting Windows 7 Home Premium with Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, bootloader

I have a machine with Windows 7 Home Premium installed. I've made a backup (using Acronis) of a windows 2003 server C drive. I then restored the C drive to a partition on the Win7 machine.

I've made several failed attempts to add the windows 2003 os drive to the boot loader for selection at start up. I believe my attempts have failed since the two OS's boot differently.

does anyone know how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'bcdedit' to create/update boot entries

This should help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. You can start with copying (ntldr + ntdetect.com + boot.ini) from Win 2003 partition root folder "\" to active partition "\" on your disk. (if active partition is unmapped use DiskManagement to map it temporary to a drive letter say S:)
2. Adding an loader entry for a ntldr based OS (XP, Server 2003) in Windows 7 BCD can be done with bcdedit.exe or using [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) - start tool, right click to get pop-up menu and select create NT loader. Change drive to S: (active partition) for the created loader.
3. Eventually the ARC Path in boot.ini has to be adjusted. Use [ArcPath utility](http://www.boyans.net/ArcPaths/ArcPaths.htm) to get exact mappings for your disk/partitions.

After rebooting you should get a dual-boot menu.

(Renaming boot menu entry for a loader -> change its "Description" element.)

Hope this helps for your dual-boot.